# Unity 2D Map size isn't the same on every screen resolution

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

As the title says, I'm having a problem with the 2D Map Size in my game.

I'm working with a 1920x1080 (Landscape) resolution and I'm developing a 2D Tower Defense game which should also be competitve in future.

The problem is, my map looks good in the 1920x1080 (Landscape) resolution, but when switching to 2960x1440 (Landscape) the player can see more space on the left and right of the screen which would be in a competitive unfair.

[image: Game in 1920x1080 (Landscape)]
[image: Game in 2960x1440 (Landscape)]

I'm still new to unity and I'd like to know, how I could solve this problem to make the game look the same for every screen resolution.

I didn't try anything yet because I don't know where to start handling this problem. Is it maybe solveable with scripts?